# A column has value like {10,20,30}, need to find the sum,avg,max and min of the value using SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to find the sum,avg,max and min of a column:

**Table_ab**

```
col1 | col2   | col3

ab   |10 am   | {10,20,30}

ab   |10.15am | {20,30,40}
```

**Expected result**

```
col1  | col2    | col3      | sum_col3 | avg_col3 | max_col3 | min_col3

ab    |10 am    |{10,20,30} |60        |20        |30        |  10
```

Comment: OK.  What have you attempted?

Comment: Why do you only want to return one of the rows?

Comment: You say "_need to find the sum,avg,max and min of the value_", but your expected result has no min column.

Comment: Just for eg i gave the expected result. I need all the rows in the table in result. And all aggregated values. I am not sure what to try with.

Comment: And... no-sql strikes again. I would suggest you normalize your data model, at least to 3NF.

Comment: You may want to start by parsing your string https://blogs.oracle.com/aramamoo/how-to-split-comma-separated-string-and-pass-to-in-clause-of-select-statement

Answer (score 1):

Not the best data model, as you've already been told. Anyway: one (usual) option is to  split values in `col3` into rows to perform those calculations. Here's how (sample data in lines #1 - 4; query begins at line #6):

```
SQL> with table_ab (col1, col2, col3) as
  2    (select 'ab', '10 am'  , '10,20,30' from dual union all
  3     select 'ab', '10.15am', '20,30,40' from dual
  4    ),
  5  -- split col3 into rows
  6  temp as
  7    (select col1,
  8            col2,
  9            col3,
 10            to_number(regexp_substr(col3, '[^,]+', 1, column_value)) val
 11     from table_ab cross join
 12       table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 13                           connect by level <= regexp_count(col3, ',') + 1
 14                          ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 15    )
 16  -- aggregate!
 17  select col1,
 18         col2,
 19         col3,
 20         sum(val) sum_col3,
 21         avg(val) avg_col3,
 22         max(val) max_col3,
 23         min(val) min_col3
 24  from temp
 25  group by col1, col2, col3;

CO COL2    COL3       SUM_COL3   AVG_COL3   MAX_COL3   MIN_COL3
-- ------- -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
ab 10.15am 20,30,40         90         30         40         20
ab 10 am   10,20,30         60         20         30         10

SQL>
```